# 3 column webpage collapses incorrectly on resize - [orkut clone]

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The goal is to create a webpage using Bootstrap which resembles Orkut. The problem is it's not even close to Orkut by looks/page design and the web page collapse on resize or on mobile screen. A screenshot of Orkut and the code of the webpage designed with bootstrap is below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100" data-bs-theme="auto">

<head>
  <script src="../assets/js/color-modes.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/css@3">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #d4dded;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .rt {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .hoverDiv:hover {
      background: #e4f2f9;
    }
    
    .icon {
      width: 8%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

  <header>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #bfd0ea;">
        <div>Home | Friends | Messages | Communities | Search</div>
        <div>Settings | Logout</div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <main class="flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div style="background-color:none;">
            <img src="face.jpg" /> <br/> Name Title
          </div>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Scrapbook <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Album <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Message <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Testimonial <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Bookmark <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Ignore <br/>
          <img src="icon.jpg" class="icon" /> Block <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div style="background-color: white">
            <h3><b>{Name Title}</b></h3>
            <span style="color:blue;font-size:.85em;font-weight:bold;">XX Scraps XX Photos XX Fans</span>
          </div>
          <span style="align: right">Social Professional Personal</span>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row hoverDiv">
              <div class="col-3 rt">Relationship status</div>
              <div class="col-9">Single</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hoverDiv">
              <div class="col-3 rt">Here for</div>
              <div class="col-9">123</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hoverDiv">
              <div class="col-3 rt">About me</div>
              <div class="col-9">Single</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Communities
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3" style="background-color: #bfd0ea;">
    <div class="container">
      <span>sticky footer content</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected output:

[image: orkut]

I am new to bootstrap and as an exercise I'm trying to clone the layout and the design to some extent.

Comment: Please [edit] the Stack Snippet I've added to your question so that it includes the CSS you are asking about (relative paths will not work because the HTML is not hosted on your server -- use a CDN). Use a dummy image service to provide images if they are necessary. However, you will need to narrow your question from "it's not even close to this other site". We don't offer free website design services here.